# Header makes two empty lines before write my text

Tags: php

I have a problem sending a file to client. I want to send plain text using header, but the out file, instead of having just my content, has two empty lines at the beginning. I don't know why this happens.

The variable I use is an xml format like this:

```
$section=<book>xbook<author>nmauthor</author></book>
```

I use this code to send the file.

```
header("Content-type:text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.xml");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary"); 
header("Pragma:no-cache");
header("Expires:0");
echo $section
```

I will be very grateful if someone helps me.

Answer (score 1):

Could be many things... for one, if you have no space before your opening php tag, one thing to look at would be the file's encoding type.  If you're using UTF-8, especially, make sure it is "without BOM" as that could cause your problem.